# Async problem with React component and dispatch actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am creating a React-Redux app consuming an API built with express.js.

I have a login form and I want to display a message to a user when he/she tries to login with wrong credentials. I have tried to architect this behavior in many ways. Down here, I have one very logical and totally synchronous way.

I have set a Login component, calling a function from userActions from its props. The components are connected with `export default connect(null, { login, register })(Login);`.

Let's look at login for now. I'll leave the code for registration there because I don't know if/how that affects my login functionality. My problem is that I can get the notifications created and the login and verification happen as expected, but I am not able to get the "auth" status, which is necessary in order to decide the redirect..

I have to handle 2 scenarios:

1. login success => redirect to '/' displaying a welcome message;
2. login failure => display an error message on the same page.

I can get the notifications created and the login and verification happen as expected, but I am not able to get the "auth" status, which is necessary in order to decide the redirect.

Can anyone help me with that? Thank you!

**onSubmit method @login.js:**

```js
onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { name, email, password } = this.state;

    // Check For Errors
    {....}

    // Register or login and notify user
    let auth = false;
    if (this.state.register) {
      this.props.register({ name, email, password })
        .then((res) => { auth = res.success; console.log(`register then: ${res}`); })
    } else {
      this.props.login({ email: email, password: password })
        .then((res) => { auth = res.success; console.log(`login then: ${res}`); })
    }

    if (auth) { this.props.history.push('/') }
  }
```

**login method @userActions.js:**

```js
export const login = authData => async dispatch => {

  axios.post('/api/v1/users/login', authData)
    .then(res => {
      beginSession(res);

      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN,
        payload: res.data.user
      });

      notifyUser('login', dispatch, res);

      return { success: true }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return { success: false }
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

**here are the components load a before an API call response**
you check before render repose get

```
//create a  use state variable for validation return a response  

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    login:'' }
   };

// any method here
onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
}
/* api call*/
{
this.setState({
                login: json.error.message
              });
// other code
}

render() {  

    if (!this.state.user ) {
      return null;
    }


    return (
      <>
//componest wait still not get repose 

<p>{this.state.login} <p>
<>
}

....
```

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. Why is there a constructor inside an onSubmit?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create the experience that I wanted using componentDidUpdate to check for the state.user, which gets updated from a login.

```
componentDidUpdate = () => {
    if (Object.keys(this.props.user).length !== 0) { this.props.history.push('/') }
  }

...

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login, register })(Login);
```

Comment: I suggest you check out how to develop that same functionality using React Hooks. It makes listening to a change and managing a component's state much easier. I have struggled with similar challenges myself and in my opinion, Hooks are a great improvement.